# Spring Boot Maven pom.xml error

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I am using Spring Boot to build an application. I downloaded initialized zip project file from [start.spring.io/](https://start.spring.io/). When I import the project I am getting the following error. By googling I could hardly understand it is proxy or connection issue. But I am able to open the url in browser.

Some people mentioned to change in settings.xml in maven. My eclipse implicitly comes with maven so I did not install maven separately. I tried adding proxy in eclipse as well. But no luck.

[image: start.spring.io/]

Comment: you need update maven project

Comment: Right click on project in eclispe -> select maven -> select update projecct -> check option given below force to update the snapshots/ relaese -> click on ok

Comment: You are not allowed to download the correct versions of Spring Boot from Maven Central. Have you correctly configured a repository manager or correctly configured your settings.xml having the correct repositories..

Comment: @khmarbaise I have downloaded initialized project from spring site. I am just importing that. I had done it before as well. But this time i am facing such issue. where will i get settings.xml I have not set maven explicitly?

Comment: @DipakThoke , I had done this. But no luck.